# Assert conn was redirected in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Please im writing a test that would check that a user is redirected to a particular URL if they are logged in and try to visit certain URLs

```
#auth.ex
def authenticated_user(conn,_opts) do
  if conn.assigns.current_user do
    conn
    |> redirect(to: Helpers.user_path(conn,:dashboard))
    |> halt()
  end
  conn
end

# router.ex
pipe_through [:browser, :authenticated_user]
get "/signup", UserController, :new
get "/signin", SessionController, :new

#_test.ex
setup %{conn: conn} = config  do
  if email = config[:login_as ] do
    user = insert_user(%{email: "demo"})
    conn = assign(build_conn(),:current_user, user)
    {:ok, conn: conn, user: user}
  else
    :ok
  end
end


@tag login_as: "test user "
test "redirect already logged user when /signin or /signup is visited ", %{conn: conn} do
  Enum.each([
    get(conn, session_path(conn, :new)),
    get(conn, user_path(conn, new)),
  ], fn conn ->
    assert redirected_to(conn,302) == "/dashboard" 
  end)
end
```

The test still fails after implementation. Please what am I missing?

Comment: Please add the ex_unit output

Comment: RuntimeError Expected redirection with status 302,got: 200

Comment: This suggests the problem is in your controller. Please post the controller code for `SessionController.create` and `UserController.create`

Comment: @MikeBuhot, I've made changes to my Question with the relevant code

Comment: That code looks fine too. How is the test establishing the `conn.assigns.current_user`?

Comment: @MikeBuhot, Made a further edit

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong, unless `insert_user` is returning `nil`.
Try sticking an `IO.puts` statement after `if conn.assigns.current_user do` to confirm that the redirect code is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the correct implementation needs to handle the else case. A plug always excepts a conn to be retuned.

```
#auth.ex
def authenticated_user(conn,_opts) do
  # Don't use the `.` below. It will fail if the map does not have the key.
  if conn.assigns[:current_user] do    
    conn
    |> redirect(to: Helpers.user_path(conn,:dashboard))
    |> halt()   # stops the remaining plugs from being run.
  else
    # just returning conn will allow the requested page to be rendered
    conn
  end
end
```

Comment: this is Obviously a better and accurate solution

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last `conn` . Tested your code, status `200` is being returned eventually.

```
#auth.ex
def authenticated_user(conn,_opts) do
if conn.assigns.current_user do
conn #<-- 302 returned here
|> redirect(to: Helpers.user_path(conn,:dashboard))
|> halt()
end
#conn <-- Remove this line, "" returned here
end
```

Hope it helps